# Entity Framework 4.0 Entity SQL passing null ObjectParameter parameters

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-sql

I have an Entity SQL query:

```
SELECT VALUE t FROM MyEntities AS t 
WHERE t.Name = @p OR (@p IS NULL AND t.Name IS NULL)
```

I can execute the query as follows:

```
var results = context.CreateQuery<WorkflowInstance>(
    query, new ObjectParameter("p", name)).ToList();
```

However, if the 'name' variable is null, then I get the System.ArgumentNullException. So I also tried to use DBNull.Value if the name was null, and I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was caught
>   Message=The specified
>   parameter type 'System.DBNull' is not
>   valid. Only scalar types, such as
>   System.Int32, System.Decimal,
>   System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are
>   supported.

I would like to have parameterized queries where null values are also possible parameter values. How do I achieve this with Entity SQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right, seems to be a bug in the ObjectParameter constructor. 
But the Value property seems to accept null values.
Try to replace your code with:

```
var prm = new ObjectParameter("p", typeof(string));
prm.Value = name;

var results = context.CreateQuery<WorkflowInstance>(
    query, prm).ToList();
```

If you assign the Value parameter directly the code seems to work.

Davide

Answer (score 1):

Nice post Davide, I used this fix to pass an integer value;

```
var prm = new ObjectParameter("pName", typeof(int));
prm.Value = pmId;
```